# changing the format of datetime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to change the timestamp from one format to another. I tried some approaches but i am not able to succeed.

```
from datetime import datetime
x=datetime.now()

z=datetime.strftime(x,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

print(z)
print(type(z))

y=datetime.strptime(z,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

print(y)
print(type(z))
```

I want to print in format as z but type should remain datetime, as z is str and if I am converting to str to datetime format, it is changing to default automatically.

Comment: If `y` is a `datetime`, you can't change the way `print(y)` renders it. You get the default format. If you don't want the default format, you convert it to a string, as you are doing with `z`, and print that instead. The  internal representation of a `datetime` is quite distant from either string representation, and you can't change it without rewriting the `datetime` class. (Not recommended.)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including desired output and actual output. You can [edit]. I ask because I'm not sure what you mean by "type should remain datetime", and I think you're missing the point of converting a datetime to str, as BoarGules wrote. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You might also want to read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).